# Como verificar se no final da String é um ou zero?

Tags: java, string

Como posso verificar se no final de uma *string* é `0`?

O problema desse código é que a *string* pode conter:

> jrp_documento.jrp_doc_001fornecedor|0

A minha necessidade é verificar se no fim da *string* é `1`ou `0`.

Identifiquei outro problema também. Como essa *string* é o nome da tabela no banco de dados é necessário ficar igual a tabela, eu dou `replaceAll` ali no `0` se conter `0`, mas se a *string* conter `0` ele retira e não é para retirar a não ser que a o `0` esteja no final. O que faço?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nomeColuna = null;
    String coluna = null;
    String sampleString = "jrp_documento.jrp_doc_fornecedor|0";

    String[] items = sampleString.split(";");
    List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList(items);

    for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
       coluna = items[i].replaceAll("[|]", "");            
       coluna =  coluna.replaceAll("[.]", "_");
       if(coluna.contains("0")){

           nomeColuna = coluna.replaceAll("0", "");
           System.out.println(nomeColuna);
           System.out.println(" é zero ");

      }else{

        nomeColuna = coluna.replaceAll("1", "");
        System.out.println(nomeColuna);
        System.out.println(" é um ");

      }             
  }
```

Comment: Você precisa verificar se items possui 0 no final?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, e ele não pode modificar os outros zeros que a String possui, somente retirar o zero ou um do final mesmo...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`String#endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)):

```
System.out.println("jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_nome|0".endsWith("0"));      // true
System.out.println("jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_sobrenome|1".endsWith("0")); // false
```

Também é possível usar a função [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

```
String sampleString1 = "jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_nome|0";
String sampleString2 = "jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_sobrenome|1";

String ultimo1 = sampleString1.substring(sampleString1.length() - 1);
String ultimo2 = sampleString2.substring(sampleString2.length() - 1);

System.out.println(ultimo1.equals("0")); // true
System.out.println(ultimo2.equals("0")); // false
```

**Edição**

> Identifiquei outro problema também. Como essa *string* é o nome da
>   tabela no banco de dados é necessário ficar igual a tabela, eu dou
>   `replaceAll` ali no 0 se conter 0, mas se a string conter 0 ele retira e
>   não é para retirar a não ser que a o 0 esteja no final. O que faço?

Não é necessário o [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), o [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) também funciona neste caso.

Escolha um dos métodos acima para verificar o final da *string*, se a condição que você quer for satisfeita, extraia todos os caracteres menos o último, segue abaixo uma forma de fazer isso com o [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```
String sampleString = "jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_nome|0;jrp_jasper.jrp_jas_sobrenome|1";
String[] items = sampleString.split(";");

for(String item: items){
    String nomeColuna = item.replace("|", "").replace(".", "_");

    if (nomeColuna.endsWith("0")){
        // Se terminar em 0
        nomeColuna = nomeColuna.substring(0, nomeColuna.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(nomeColuna);
    }
    else if (nomeColuna.endsWith("1")){
        // Se terminar em 1
        System.out.println(nomeColuna);
    }
    else{
        // Não termina em 0 nem 1
        System.out.println(nomeColuna);
    }
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/97qVkM)

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o que precisa ser verificado são as Strings do vetor items. Acredito que `samplestring` do código foi apenas para fins de teste, numa outra pergunta, essa string continha vários outros valores separados por `;`

Comment: @diegofm Eu editei a resposta e coloquei isso também. :)

Comment: Deu certo Oo. Estou estudando o substring aqui para ver melhor o seu funcionamento. Valeu cara, você salvou a minha vida. Sempre é bom ver a forma como outros programadores programam a gente aprende bastante.

Answer (score 11):

```
    String sampleString = "jrp_documento.jrp_doc_fornecedor|0";
    String[] items = sampleString.split(";");
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].charAt(items[i].length()-1) == '0'){
            System.out.println(items[i] + " termina em zero");
        }else{
            System.out.println(items[i] + " nao termina em zero");
        }   
    }
```

O código acima pega a `String`, isola o ultimo caractere com [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)), e verifica se ele é igual a 0.

Veja no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/hJtij0).

Comment: mais tarde testo.

Comment: Negativar é facil, dificil é colaborar com o site e apontar o erro na resposta.

Answer (score 11):

Para verificar no final use endsWith, ex:

```
str.endsWith("0") || str.endsWith("1")
```

Comment: Essa resposta parece está mais correta para mim. Mas eu ainda terei que bolar um jeito de arrancar esse 0 ou 1 do final somente...senão vai dar conflito com as tabelas lá no banco de dados...porque o replace retira tudo da String...

Comment: Vou testar depois, vou assistir aula. Falo mais tarde

Comment: simples brother, ex:

` if(str.endsWith("0") || str.endsWith("1")) {
    str = str.substring(0,str.length() - 1);
} `
  
` System.out.println(str); `

Comment: desculpa a formatação, estava fazendo outra coisa e passou 5min e não deixou editar :(

Comment: :) Tudo bem. Brother.